# Is this prepositional phrase or introductory clause?

Tags: clauses, prepositional-phrases

“Out of respect for the rest of the class”

The full sentence is: "Out of respect for the rest of the class, please arrive on time."

Comment: It's an introductory prepositional phrase.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How did you manage to identify that it's a prepositional phrase?

Comment: It is a preposition phrase headed by the prep "out". The PP functions as an adjunct of purpose, and is fairly mobile: "Please arrive on time out of respect for the rest of the class" is reasonably acceptable, at least grammatically so.

Answer (score 1):

In traditional terminology, [*a clause*](https://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/clause-phrase.asp) must have a subject and a finite verb:

> If you value courtesy and respect for your classmates, you will arrive on time.

This sentence has two clauses:

- a conditional clause: *If you value courtesy... subject: you, verb: value*
- an independent clause: *you will arrive on time. subject: you, verb: will arrive.*

A *phrase* is a group of words performing the same function in a sentence:

- Noun phrase: *the best Chinese restaurant*
- verb phrase: *will have been working*
- prepositional phrase: *over the river*

Your example sentence

> Out of respect for the rest of the class, please arrive on time.

begins with three prepositional phrases. There is no verb. The prepositions are in bold:

- ***out of** respect*
- ***for** the rest*
- ***of** the class*

Thus it can only be termed an introductory phrase.

Comment: Note, however, that the subject may well be missing from a subordinate clause, especially infinitives and gerunds, while there is **always** a verb, either finite (either present or past tense) or non-finite (infinitive or participle) in a clause. No verb, no clause. And contrariwise, the number of verbs in a sentence equals the number of clauses; yes verb, yes clause. If it's a constituent of more than one word, and it's not a clause, then it's a phrase.

Comment: That's why I added the caveat "traditional," since the term is "participial phrase," as I recall, even if it had a subject, and a subordinate clause is one with a subordinating conjunction.

Comment: No, that's what they tell kids in third grade who ask questions, to shut them up. In fact only adverbial clauses begin with a subordinating conjunction. Noun clauses (subject or object complements) and Adjective clauses (relative clauses and NP complements) use different marking methods. Every sentence has a main clause, but there may be and usually are many other clauses, all subordinate.

Comment: If there are, as you say, many subordinate clauses, how do you explain to students beyond the third grade where to put commas of if you're using English grammar terms to teach German, when the finite verb will go to the end of the clause? Is that a dependent clause that may have one or more subordinate clauses?

Comment: You can explain to any native speaker of English to put a comma where they hear one in the speech. English commas are audible, and phonologically determined, whereas German commas are governed by grammatical rules and have no consistent intonational shape. In either event, punctuation is no part of language, since it's part of writing, not speech.

Comment: Actually, commas in German are pretty much the same as they are in English, except there is no such thing as an Oxford comma or a restrictive relative clause. All _Nebensätze_ — you have yet to tell me what you call the English equivalent — are set off by commas.

Comment: No, in English one would never write _I think, that he left already_; it would not sound right with a comma. And subject complements don't get a comma, either: _For him to leave early, would be a mistake_ is wrong. Dunno about German.

Comment: Those are both _Nebensätze_ that get commas, which I already mentioned. The second would literally be: That he early way-goes, would-be a mistake.

Comment: @JohnLawler: You said, "English commas are audible, and phonologically determined, whereas German commas are governed by grammatical rules and have no consistent intonational shape." This is absolutely not true. Commas in English *and* in German are based on both pronunciation and syntax; each language just applies each factor differently in the mix. Please don't say things like that!

Comment: @Cerberus: You say "based on"; sorry, that seems like handwaving. I know of no rules except syntactic ones governing commas in German, and no rules (that work) for English commas that don't refer to intonation.

Comment: @John: Any serious book concerning English punctuation or German punctuation. (For one thing, pausing and syntax are connected to a significant degree in both languages; it makes no sense to say that one language bases its commas only on syntax and not at all on pausing, nor the converse. And that is just the categorical problem. Practical situations where syntax has a significant influence on commas in English are easy to find, e.g. in the rarity of *\*you're a wonderful, father* (forced by syntax despite pause)  and the common occurrence of *yes, ma'am* (in quick speech without real pause).)

Comment: I think you're conflating comma usage in writing with intonation. Commas exist only in writing, and intonation (not "pauses", btw -- there's rarely unfilled time in speech) only in speech. There are a lot of different intonation contours with syntactic effect in English, and some of them are sometimes signalled by commas in writing, by some writers. By others not so much. Still others hear them all over the place, it appears.